# Caluculate green area between two curves on left hand side and right hand

Tags: python, scipy, curve, integral

Hello how can i calculate the value of the green area (in python) which lies on the left from the blue line and on than the others on the right of the blue line?

so only where the black line is above the yellow line (the lines are resulting from an array not a function)

[image: Shows an ilustrativ curve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your vectors of your black line `f` and your yellow line `g` are defined at the same points, you can integrate the curve `h = f - g` where `h` is greater than zero:

```py
h = f - g
h_positive = h * (h>0)
```

[image: Plot of h_positive with a vertical line showing a cutoff]

If your `x` values are stored in a vector `xx` and your cutoff between the two parts of your plot is `cutoff` (the blue line) then you can calculate the integral of `h_positive` numerically with [`numpy.trapz`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html):

```py
cutoff_idx = np.where(xx >= cutoff)[0][0]

left_area = np.trapz(h_positive[:cutoff_idx], xx[:cutoff_idx])
right_area = np.trapz(h_positive[cutoff_idx:], xx[cutoff_idx:])

print(f'Left area: {left_area}')
print(f'Right area: {right_area}')
print(f'Difference: {left_area - right_area}')
```

Example output (with estimated input data):

```
Left area: 0.0034731843629035204
Right area: 0.021175629261965995
Difference: -0.017702444899062475
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the black line be a function f(x) and yellow be g(x). What you want to do is calculate the integral:

[image] where a and b are intersection points of f(x) and g(x) at the interval where g(x) < f(x). In your example you will have to calculate 3 such integrals.

Algorithmically speaking what you have to do is:

1. Find the intersection of the blue line and the x-axis to split to left and right interval.
2. For each interval do the following:

   2.1. Find intersection points of f(x), g(x)

   2.2. Find the intervals for which g(x) < f(x)

   2.3. For each interval of step 2.2:

   2.3.1 Calculate the integral mentioned above to find the green area

I haven't worked with Python for Mathematical computations so I can't really guide you through the Python steps but hopefully my comment along with your googling skills can give you the specifics.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that the two functions are arrays and not real functions

Comment: @SticktoYourBoard Same difference - you can use e.g. [`scipy.trapezoid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.trapezoid.html) or some other [integrating function given fixed samples](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#integrating-functions-given-fixed-samples).

Comment: @SticktoYourBoard Even so, the methodology doesn't change. In that case you can use `scipy.optimize.fsolve` to find the intersection of the functions (with a few adjustments to the method) and `scipy.integrate.trapezoid` as per Steve's suggestion

Comment: To simplify this, you can just consider the positive values of `f - g`, for example by doing `h = f-g`, and `h_positive = h * (h>0)`.